# Diagram chase proof regarding long exact sequence

Tags: homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$I am losing my sanity over this diagram chase.

> Given an abelian category and a cochain complex $A$, I am trying to prove that $\ker(A^i/\im d^{i+1} \to \ker d^{i-1})$ is isomorphic to $H^i(A) = \operatorname{coker}(\im d^{i+1}\to \ker d^i)$.

This is apparently how you get the long exact sequence from the snake lemma if you apply it to the correct diagram but I cannot confirm this without going into an element-wise proof. All I can get is a morphism from $H^i(A)$ to the other object but not the other way around and this is the only way I know how to show that two objects are isomorphic.

Am I supposed to use the fact that coimages are isomorphic to images in abelian categories? Because that did not help much either. A tip would be appreciated if it's possible.

Comment: I believe this should be a trivial result as it is basically in every textbook but wherever I have checked, the authors only say that by applying the snake lemma to a specified diagram, we get the long exact sequence. One source is this: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0111 . And it is easy to show if you invoke an embedding theorem but I cannot verify it with a diagram chase.

Comment: Edited. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome.  I'm taking a crack at it using https://q.uiver.app

Comment: What is $A^i/\operatorname{im} d^{i+1}$ defined as if you can't take elements?

Comment: if $X\to Y$ is a monomorphism, then $Y/X =coker(X\to Y)$